# bootstrap 3.0 popover width issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a popover that is rendering very strange. It renders very tall and thin. Not what is expected but curious how I can fix this.

```
<div class="input-group">
 <input id="JewelryDescription" name="JewelryDescription" 
   data-bind="value: JewelryDescription" 
   type="text" class="form-control control-font">
 <span class="input-group-addon">
 <a tabindex="0" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" title="" 
 data-content="Here is where the content goes and goes and could 
 go on and on and for awhile but should have some sort of limit." 
 data-original-title="Title">Help <i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i></a>                                                          </span>
```

```
$(function () {
    // popup functionality 
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    });
});
```

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/xequence/t76wkysz/1/

Comment: Define your width and height for the div (using CSS or inline) and it shouldn't render that way. It is probably rendering based on %s and screen sizes so try pixels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `data-placement="left"` and it will have enough room and stay a normal size.

https://jsfiddle.net/t76wkysz/2/